# Abort compilation when modern runtime or autosynthesized properties are not available

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I wrote a Mac + iOS library which depends on autosynthesized properties. I had someone try to compile it under 32-bit, ignore a bunch of compiler warnings, and get unrecognized selectors at runtime.

Since none of the code will work without implementing a bunch of getters and setters, I'd prefer to stop them with a `#error` instead.

I thought I could do this:

```
#if !__has_feature(objc_default_synthesize_properties)
#error This library requires the modern runtime and will not compile under 32-bit
#endif
```

But it has no effect.

To get the result I want, I have to do this:

```
#if !__has_feature(objc_default_synthesize_properties) || defined(__i386__)
#error This library requires the modern runtime and will not compile under 32-bit
#endif
```

I know there are other instances besides 32-bit Intel architecture which will cause the problem, such as old versions of Mac OS.

Is there a better macro for checking the availability of autosynthesized properties or the modern runtime?

Comment: The old 32-bit runtime didn't support synthesis, so getters and setters were explicit.  You don't necessarily need the @property directive, just to be more specific about your methods.  Also, Cocoa Touch is 32-bit, and this really doesn't have anything to do with it, especially because every iOS device supports the modern runtime.

Comment: Edited about the `@synthesize` bit. Regarding the tags, the question is relevant to Mac and iOS: you just answered the iOS part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the modern runtime was available starting with Mac OS X 10.5, the macro `#if MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_5` should evaluate correctly if a given system supports the modern runtime.  A check for the `i386` architecture may also be required.  The above can also be checked for with `NSAppKitVersionNumber10_5`

On iOS the check is unnecessary, as every iOS device supports the modern Objective-C runtime, and therefore, also supports variable synthesis.

Here's some macros which also incorporate Steven Fisher's answer. They should work on either platform, and check for both a modern compiler and the modern runtime:

```
#if !( defined(__clang__) && __has_feature(objc_default_synthesize_properties) && \
       ( TARGET_OS_IPHONE || \
         ( NSAppKitVersionNumber10_5 && !defined(__i386__) ) ) )
#error This library requires autosynthesized properties
#endif
```

Comment: If you can integrate it smoothly, knock yourself out.  Otherwise, just edit the body of the question.

Comment: Applying this macro to another problem, I'm realizing that I'm not correctly using MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED. It doesn't work correctly if I change the rhs to NSAppKitVersionNumber10_7 e.g. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @noa I didn't realized you had edited the code that Much!  AppKit defines and the OS X version defines are different entities.  Drop the comparison and use only `NSAppKitVersionNumber10_5` because it is only defined for 10.5's AppKit and higher.

Comment: Thanks. One caveat is that this necessarily only checks the SDK, not the deployment target. It seems I might also need to check `NSAppKitVersionNumber` at runtime, for the sake of completeness.